# How to replace a html entity within script tags using Craft replace

Tags: templating, javascript, array, replace

Apologies if this has been asked before, I can only find questions dealing with the reverse scenario (i.e. replacing special characters with html entities)

I need to output special characters as part of a JavaScript array using Craft. Currently the values are output with all special characters replaced by their html equivalent. (e.g.: ampersands are replaced by &amp )

I have tried restoring the special characters using craft replace but without success.

The following code works to replace text, but does not, for example, replace &amp with &, or rather perhaps it does not distinguish these values as distinct.

```
<script>

    var myVariable = [{% for value in myArray %}"{{ value|replace('raw-html-entity', 'special-character') }}"{%- if not loop.last -%},{% endif %}{% endfor %}];

</script>
```

This code is being used for an array which is used for jQuery autocomplete values, so raw html is not appropriate.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a [Craft Helpers](https://github.com/carlcs/craft-helpers) plugin on GitHub, which has a `htmlEntityDecode` Twig filter.

```
{{ value|htmlEntityDecode}}
```

Comment: Thanks,

htmlEntityDecode did the trick.

Didn't seem to work with the striptags filter by the way.

Comment: I up-voted but it wont display as I'm a noob.

Comment: Sorry, should have made clear that `striptags` would further get rid of HTML tags after you converted all your HTML entities. Seems like you have non, as I could have already guessed from your question. Will get rid of it in the answer. Oh and thanks for the up-vote anyway :)